# MySQL Query optimisation advice

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I'm running the below query and wanted to ask about how i could optimise this query. This query has been in use where i work for a while and i have the feeling that it could be optimised as its run regularly with different parameters for reporting purposes

First run takes around 2 minutes. Subsequent runs take around 30s as the query cache has kicked in i believe.

The `tags` table has over 15million rows and contains tags for `users` as well as other tables like `companies`.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` enum('company','review','job','sector','user') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'company',
`fk_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`tag_key` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
`tag_value` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `tag_key_value` (`tag_key`,`tag_value`) USING BTREE,
KEY `fk_id_key` (`fk_id`,`tag_key`) USING BTREE,
FULLTEXT KEY `tag_value` (`tag_value`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15725767 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The `users` table has around 450k rows.

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`title` int(1) NOT NULL,
`firstname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`surname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`university` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`university_start_year` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`university_end_year` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`degree_discipline` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`signup_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`newsletter_subscription` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
...
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `university` (`university`) USING BTREE,
KEY `university_start_year` (`university_start_year`) USING BTREE,
KEY `university_end_year` (`university_end_year`) USING BTREE,
KEY `degree_discipline` (`degree_discipline`) USING BTREE,
..
KEY `email` (`email`),
FULLTEXT KEY `firstname` (`firstname`,`surname`,`comments`,`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1188075 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I don't have the ability to change the table structure or indexes so any input on the optimising the query would be greatly appreciated. I thought that maybe using sub queries or optimising how the joins work would be the first point to address but i'm a bit lost of how i would tackle this.

```
SELECT u.firstname, u.email
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN tags as tags ON tags.fk_id = u.id AND tags.type = "user" AND tags.tag_key = "option"
LEFT JOIN tags as tags6 ON tags6.fk_id = u.id AND tags6.type = "user" AND tags6.tag_key = "role"
LEFT JOIN tags as tags7 ON tags7.fk_id = u.id AND tags7.type = "user" AND tags7.tag_key = "sector"
WHERE (user_type IN ("1")) AND 
(tags.tag_key = "option" AND tags.tag_value IN ("1", "2", "8")) AND 
((degree_discipline IN ("ACC", "ACT", "ACF", "INS", "CBN", "INV", "RBN", "BNK", "ECO", "FIN", "MAT"))
OR (tags6.tag_key = "role" AND tags6.tag_value IN ("ACC", "ACT", "ACF", "INS", "CBN", "INV", "RBN", "BNK", "ECO", "FIN", "MAT"))
OR (tags7.tag_key = "sector" AND tags7.tag_value IN ("ACC", "ACT", "ACF", "INS", "CBN", "INV", "RBN", "BNK", "ECO", "FIN", "MAT"))) AND 
(u.signup_date >= "2012-09-01" ) AND 
newsletter_subscription = "1" 
GROUP BY u.email
```

Explain

[image]

If there's any other information that i can provide that would be helpful let me know.

**Server Environment**

These queries are being run on a replication slave for reporting purposes. This replication server has hourly backups run on it via `mysqldump` which could be affecting the caches but thats only a guess at this point.

Comment: if the output of the query is from only Users table, why are you trying the left joins?

Comment: @SQL.RK the left joins are there so we filter the `tags` table. Is there a better way to combine this data so i  canfilter the rows in the `tags` table related to the `users.id`. I haven't got a lot of experience with SQL so if there's a more efficient way to tackle this i'd open to any suggestions.

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` together with `OR` is really off-the-wall.  For example, `tag6` might have zero (`LEFT`) or more (`JOIN`) rows for this user, if it does have any rows, then include the user if key and value are role and ...; `OR` include the user for other reasons.

Comment: @RickJames thanks for the input, would you be able to provide an example or some pointers on how i would use your feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EAV (key-value) schema is clumsy and hard to optimize.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

What table(s) are `newsletter_subscription` and `degree_discipline` in?

These should help:

```
tags:   INDEX(fk_id, type, tag_key)
users:  INDEX(newsletter_subscription, user_type, signup_date)
```

The Query cache, if invoked, will take only milliseconds, not 30s.  It sounds like other I/O caching kicked in.

Also, try this...  Try 3 queries, each with one of the `OR` clauses.  While doing it, see if you can simplify each.  For example, when fetching tag6, there is no need to join to tag7.  If they add it up to less than 2 minutes (or 30 sec), we can discuss using `UNION` to finish out the query.

A few more hints...

```
( SELECT u.firstname, u.email
    FROM users AS u
    LEFT JOIN tags as tags ON tags.fk_id = u.id
                          AND tags.type = "user"
                          AND tags.tag_key = "option"
    LEFT JOIN tags as tags6 ON tags6.fk_id = u.id
             AND tags6.type = "user" AND tags6.tag_key = "role"
    LEFT JOIN tags as tags7 ON tags7.fk_id = u.id
              AND tags7.type = "user" AND tags7.tag_key = "sector"
    WHERE (user_type IN ("1"))
      AND (tags.tag_key = "option" AND tags.tag_value IN ("1", "2", "8"))
      AND ((degree_discipline IN ("ACC", "ACT", "ACF", "INS", "CBN", "INV", "RBN", "BNK", "ECO", "FIN", "MAT"))
) UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ... same ...
    FROM ... same ...
    WHERE ... second part of OR ...
) UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ... 3rd ...
) GROUP BY u.email
```

Comment: and after create indexes (if not already) - direct go to "Also, try this ..." :) UNION work much faster than OR for different tables (self join as well). if it not resolve all problem - at least make it faster and more easy to profile each sub-query separate.

Comment: I've added the create statements and further detail on the server these queries are being run on. `newsletter_subscription` and `degree_discipline` are both in the users table. i'll give you suggestions ago now.

Comment: This needs to be a learning exercise for you, too, but I added some more hints.